# Merge-sort in a Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, mergesort

I am currently practicing or my interview and was doing the merge-sort for the linked list problem.

Given a linked list (has `next` and `val` attributes), `4-2-1-3`, I am supposed to sort it to be `1-2-3-4` in `O(nlogn)`. So, I tried to use merge sort to a linked list. Below is my code.

```
def sortList(self, head):
    """
    :type head: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """

    if head.next:

        # find mid point

        mid = fast = head
        while fast.next and fast.next.next:
            mid = mid.next
            fast = fast.next.next

        # split linkedList into two

        L = head
        R = mid.next
        mid.next = None

        # recursively call mergeSort to Left and Right Lists

        self.sortList(L)
        self.sortList(R)

        # pointers for merging

        newPtr = newHead = ListNode(-1)
        newHead.next = newPtr

        # merge and sort

        while L and R:
            if L.val < R.val:
                newPtr.next = L
                L = L.next
            else:
                newPtr.next = R
                R = R.next
            newPtr = newPtr.next
        # for remaining nodes
        while L:
            newPtr.next = L
            newPtr = newPtr.next
            L = L.next
        while R:
            newPtr.next = R
            newPtr = newPtr.next
            R = R.next

        return newHead.next

    else:
        return head
```

I feel like my merge sort algorithm is correct, but my result for the input above gives me `1-3-4` missing the `2`.

I think I am really close, but I am not sure which part I am messing up.

Please help.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem by changing `L` and `R` to `l1` and `l2` and changing

```
        self.sortList(L)
        self.sortList(R)
```

This to

```
        L = self.sortList(l1)
        R = self.sortList(l2)
```

Other parts are identical and now I have the same answer. However, I am not sure how the change made the difference.

Comment: "but my result for the input above gives me 1-3-4 missing the 2." Then your algorithm isn't correct. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code so that you can find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling sortList recursively, the local function variables R and L may no longer be the head of their respective list segments.  The subsequent merge operation would then "skip" the parts of the sorted lists that precede the original nodes resulting in an incomplete output.

Your change ensured that R and L have the effective head of each sub list to merge by re-assigning them with the head of the sorted chains.